# Android ActionBarSherlock how to add three menuItems?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I can add only two of menuItems. Why cann`t I add more?
I`m doing this in common way:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.step_menu,  menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

But in my xml there is four items. Inflater inflates only two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add to your items in your_menu.xml:

```
<item
     ...
     android:showAsAction="always" />
```

If this didn't help post your menu.xml.

Answer (score 1):

The items are always there, but not visible. If you press the menu button (or the more button in the actionbar for devices without the fysical menu button), the rest of the buttons appear. 
This is because the ActionBar thinks it doesn't have enough space for all buttons.

By showing the item `always` as bondoleg proposed, you risk overlap of the items on smaller devices. Therefore it is recommended to use `never` or `ifRoom`.

Comment: The point is I cannot see any "more" button. Also I cannot see them while invoking menu.